# Create function for Order Button: identify which thumbnail was selected and capture image number?

Tags: javascript

I have a series of thumbnails on a page. The function listed below sets a thumbnail's state to "Selected" once clicked on.  I want my  Order Button to capture this image's thumbnail style number.(see Example 2.) but I need help writing a function to capture the selected thumbnail's information. Help please!

```
function updateThumbnails(){
$('.gallery_thumbnails a').each(function(index){

    if ( $('.gallery_preview a').attr('href') == $(this).attr('href') ){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).children().fadeTo(250, .6);
    }else {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).children().css('opacity', '1');
    }
});
```

}

Example 2: I need this images style number ( 634_RC.jpg. )which is a "child" of the "parent"

```
<div class="gallery_thumbnails">
    <a href="gallery/634-azalea-branch_fullsize.jpg" title="634-azalea-branch"><img src="gallery-thumbnail/634_RC.jpg" alt="634-azalea-branch"/></a>
```